# Non-English characters in PHP

Tags: php, html, file, encoding, entities

im having a problem with writing a Non-English characters into file (.txt) using php .
 this is my code :

```
$str = "â€êþÿûîœøîô‘ë’ðüïlæß€¿×÷¡ï";
$str = htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES, mb_detect_encoding($str));
$str =htmlspecialchars_decode(html_entity_decode($str),ENT_QUOTES);
$f = fopen("test.txt","w");
fputs($f,$str);
fclose($f);
```

when i open the file the result is : `â&euro;êþÿûîœøîô‘ë’ðüïlæß&euro;¿×÷¡ï`

as you see for example the euro symbol still no appear correctly in the file and other symbols .

any one have an idea to fix this problem ?

Comment: The string you pasted seems identical with the string in the file. What exactly goes wrong? What is all this encoding and decoding good for? It doesn't seem to make sense at all

Comment: If you serve the page using UTF-8, you won't need any entities other than `&amp;`, `&gt;` and `&lt;`.

Comment: it's not identical because in the file some symbol like euro still in as html entity " & euro ;"

Comment: @user742002: That wasn't obvious in the original post; @Pekka and I have added the formating to make this stand out.

Answer (score 3):

The conversion of `€` to `&euro;` is done by the `htmlentities()` function; since you are encoding into HTML entities and decoding right after, I'd suggest to leave this step out:

```
$str = "â€êþÿûîœøîô‘ë’ðüïlæß€¿×÷¡ï";
$f = fopen("test.txt","w");
fputs($f,$str);
fclose($f);
```

Comment: when i let the code same of yours the result in the file comes like that : Ã¢â‚¬ÃªÃ¾Ã¿Ã»Ã®Å“Ã¸Ã®Ã´â€˜Ã«â€™Ã°Ã¼Ã¯lÃ¦ÃŸâ‚¬Â¿Ã—Ã·Â¡Ã¯

Comment: @user[0-9]+: What is the character encoding of your PHP file? What is the apparent character encoding of the output file? (if you're opening it in Notepad, it will usually look weird; Notepad is notoriously crappy in handling charsets outside ASCII) See also: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: character encoding of my php file is UTF-8 , and the output file with the code in original post is : â & euro ;êþÿûî&oelig;øîô &lsquo ;ë& rsquo;ðüïlæß & euro ;¿×÷¡ï

Comment: and when i open it with sublime editor or gedit it looks like in the browzer

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to keep this encoding/decoding business (it looks like you're trying to use the encode/decode process to convert between character sets?):

In your encoding step, you use `mb_detect_encoding` on the input string and pass that to `htmlentities`, which allows the euro sign in your input to be correctly detected (most of the time).

However, in your decoding step, you don't specify any charset, so `html_entity_decode` will pick ISO-8859-1, which doesn't include the euro sign.

If you want to keep this code block mostly the same, you need to pick a charset to decode to that includes all the characters you want (like UTF-8 or ISO-8859-15).

**Edit:** Here's an example based on your code (I picked ISO-8859-15, but you really need to know or decide what output character set you want):

```
$str = "â€êþÿûîœøîô‘ë’ðüïlæß€¿×÷¡ï";
$str = htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES, mb_detect_encoding($str));
$str = html_entity_decode($str, ENT_QUOTES, 'ISO-8859-15');
$f = fopen("test.txt","w");
fputs($f,$str);
fclose($f);
```

Comment: so can you give me an example using some lines of code plz :)

Comment: when i tryed your code it gives me an error Warning: html_entity_decode(): charset `IS0-8859-15' not supported, assuming iso-8859-1

Comment: fixed, I am dumb and typed a zero instead of O.

Comment: By the way, while I think my example should get fix your euro sign problem, you really should think about why you're doing this conversion. If you control the input and output, as you do here, you should just encode the input (your php file) in the correct encoding to begin with.  If you really do think you need to convert encodings, you could more directly use the PHP functions that are intended for this purpose like `mb_convert_encoding` or `iconv`.